# Objective-C - Use of undeclared identifier, when its defined

Tags: objective-c

I have this button defined in my viewDidLoad:

```
UIBarButtonItem *lotBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Lot" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
```

and I am getting an error on this line:

```
[lotBtn setTitle:unitPickerSelectionString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Use of undeclared identifier 'lotBtn'

do I need to define the lotBtn in my .h file: ?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *lotBtn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects that are defined within braces `{ }` will not be accessible outside of the braces (unless passed).

Your property implementation will work. You'll also be able to access that property from outside of your class too. If you want it only in the current class (which I imagine you might) you can define it another way like so:

```
@implementation YourViewController {
    UIBarButtonItem *lotBtn
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    lotBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Lot" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
}
```

Then your `UIBarButtonItem` will be available throughout your `ViewController`

Comment: You could also place the property in a class extension inside the .m file, so that it's still a property but it's private.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your reference of `lotBtn` is *below* the declaration, *in the same method*, and within *the same scope* (e.g. if statement block).

If you need to access it outside the present scope, you will have to declare it, e.g. in the way you indicated.